# Cartesian product and some properties

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I try to prove this but I don't know if my proofs are right.

1.$int(A×B)= int A × int B$, where $A \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

So we know this is true by definition of interior of a set $int A \subset A$ and $int B \subset B$ by properties of the subset and Cartesian product we have $int A × int B \subset A×B$, in addition $int A$ and $int B$ are open sets in consequence $int A × int B $ is open so int A × int B \subset int ( A×B).

$int (A×B)$ is open in consequence if I take all $B(a,r)$ and $B (b,r)$ with $a \in A$, $b \in B$ and $r>0$ I can white $ int (A×B ) = \cup_r ( B(a,r) × B(b,r))$, and we know $B(a,r)\subset A$ and $B(b,r)\subset B$ in consequence $\cup_r ( B(a,r) × B(b,r))\subset int A × int B$.

In conclusion we have 1.

2. $\overline{A×B}= \bar{A}× \bar{B}$, again by definition of closure we have $A\subset \bar{A}$ and $B \subset \bar{B}$ by properties of subset and Cartesian product $ A × B \subset \bar{A}× \bar {B}$ and $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ are closed in fact  is closed. Now I know for all closet set C that contains $\bar{A}× \bar {B}$, $A×B$ is a subset of C in consequence $\overline{A×B}\subset \bar{A}× \bar{B}$

Let $(a,b) \in \bar{A}× \bar{B}$ we have for some open ball with $r>0$, $B(a,r)\cap A\not= \emptyset$ and $B(b,r)\cap B\not= \emptyset$,if we use the property of intersection and Cartesian product we have,  $B(a,r)× B(b,r) \cap A× B \not= \emptyset$ finally we know $ B((a,b),r)\subset B(a,r)× B(b,r)$ in consequence $(a,b) \in \overline{A×B} $

We can conclude 2.

Comment: “… is open so… “ You can only conclude $int\,A\times int\,B\subseteq int(A\times B).$ You haven’t proven equality.

Comment: You are right, I fixing now.